# SIngle Query from Multiple Table MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have tables that contain same field, for example:

```
p_central_ticket        p_south_ticket             p_west_ticket 
=====================================================================
- t_id                  - t_id                     - t_id
- t_open_by             - t_open_by                - t_open_by 
- t_closed_by           - t_closed_by              - t_closed_by 
- t_open_time           - t_open_time              - t_open_time 
- t_closed_time         - t_closed_time            - t_closed_time
```

One thing that i expect is output just like this, but definitely for 3 table above in single query:

```
Name                today      weekly     monthly     yearly     
=================================================================   
test1@random.com         2           10          70        1000         
test2@random.com         5           14          60        1234
```

But, my query right now just for calculate 1 table.

```
SELECT t_closed_by As Username, ixt_user_type.user_owner As Role,
    COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 1 day THEN 1 END ) as today,
    COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 7 day THEN 1 END ) as weekly,
    COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 1 month THEN 1 END ) as monthly,
    COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 1 year THEN 1 END ) as yearly
FROM p_central_ticket
LEFT JOIN m_event_type ON p_central_ticket.t_req_type = m_event_type.ev_type
LEFT JOIN ixt_user_type ON m_event_type.ev_user_type_target = ixt_user_type.user_type
WHERE t_status = 9
GROUP BY t_closed_by;
```

My question is, how should i do, to make my query calculate from 3 tables but in single query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UNION to merge three tables and apply all your join on that merged table like below -

```
SELECT t_closed_by As Username, ixt_user_type.user_owner As Role,
    COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 1 day THEN 1 END ) as today,
    COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 7 day THEN 1 END ) as weekly,
    COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 1 month THEN 1 END ) as monthly,
    COUNT( case when t_closed_time > curdate() - interval 1 year THEN 1 END ) as yearly
FROM 
( select * from p_central_ticket 
  union 
  select * from p_south_ticket 
  union 
  select * from p_west_ticket
)A 
LEFT JOIN m_event_type ON A.t_req_type = m_event_type.ev_type
LEFT JOIN ixt_user_type ON m_event_type.ev_user_type_target = ixt_user_type.user_type
WHERE t_status = 9
GROUP BY t_closed_by
```